# Vuikit modal not showing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuikit

I am using the code from the official documentation - https://vuikit.github.io/vuikit/#/modal

```
<vk-button @click.native="show = true">
  Open
</vk-button>
<vk-modal :show="show"
  @clickOut="show = false"
  @inactive="show = false"
  @keyEsc="show = false">
  <a class="uk-close"
    @click="show = false">
  </a>
  <div class="uk-modal-header">
    <h2>Headline</h2>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  <div class="uk-modal-footer">
    Footer
  </div>
  <div class="uk-modal-caption">Caption</div>
</vk-modal>
```

All other elements of the kit seem to work fin out of the box, but not the modal - it's just not showing. Ive also tried to add data property show, like this

```
new Vue({
  data: {
    show:true,
   //..
```

Otherwise it was showing error

> Property or method "show" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data
>   properties in the data option.

You can see demo here: http://codepen.io/shershen08/pen/oYWvwo?editors=1010

What did I miss ?

Comment: hard to say to be honest. If you look into HTML it makes effect but it is not shown so it can be not related to vue as vue looks like working fine.  Maybe something caused by codepen

Comment: I agree, html is transformed correctly. But it's the same on my local version

Comment: I would suggest to rise an issue on their Github as it looks like framework related.